# SQL after trigger not counting correctly

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have two tables, `tasks` and `subtasks`. Every subtask has a status (PENDING when first inserted). Then I run threads that update every subtask (the status becomes READY). What I want is when every subtask of a given task becomes READY, their parent task to become ready as well. Here's the trigger I wrote:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_task_status() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO trigger_log SELECT NEW.subtask_id, COUNT(fo_id) FROM subtasks WHERE fo_id = NEW.fo_id AND status <> 'READY';

      UPDATE tasks
         SET status = 'READY'
       WHERE task_id = NEW.fo_id
         AND NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
               FROM subtasks
              WHERE fo_id = NEW.fo_id
                AND status <> 'READY'
             );
      RETURN NULL;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_task AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON subtasks
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_task_status();
```

When I test this with one task and 4 subtasks, here's what's inserted in the `trigger_log` table:

```
ID  Pending_count
2        3
1        3
3        3
4        3
```

And on top of that, after the test is finished, all the subtasks are in state READY, but their main task is still PENDING. Basically the trigger does not count correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112582/trigger-procedure-in-postgresql

Comment: Looks like a concurrency problem. If parallel threads access the same tasks in `READ COMMITTED` isolation mode, the results you get are expected. You may want to consider the `SERIALIZABLE` mode.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to second Daniel Vérité's suggestion to go with a serializable mode here (or a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE).

However, your question is short on details so it may not be the issue.  Here are things to check:

1. If you run the query normally does it do what you expect?  Troubleshoot your queries first.  If not, then you need to find out what data underneath is causing the problem.  Given that you seem to be using strings for status, this could be a very subtle problem like, for example, whitespace.
2. Is the trigger fired?  You can add RAISE NOTICE in your trigger to ensure you get to see in psql that it is actually firing.  If not, you need to find out why (maybe it is disabled, or your query isn't doing what you think it is doing).